# Exhausted resultset exception after a period, when application has started

Tags: java, performance, memory, jboss, sqlexception

We have a java application running on JBOSS with Oracle. We are also using the frameworks seam and hibernate.

When our application is up and running for production, after few hours of the start of the application we encounter a problem like this:

```
crms_log_27_may.txt:10:47:09,170 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
crms_log_27_may.txt:10:47:09,170 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset   
crms_log_27_may.txt:10:47:09,170 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
crms_log_27_may.txt:10:22:18,135 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
crms_log_27_may.txt:10:24:10,231 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
```

I checked all my code and found that I used `rs.next()` and closed the objects properly.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a connection pool somewhere the connections might go stale after a period of inactivity, and you need to reconfigure the connection pool to detect this so you only get good connections.

This is typically done with a simple query not changing anything, like "select 1 from dual" and if that responds correctly the connection is good and you get it.  If it doesn't it is discarded and a new created for you.